# Center Christmax Calendar

Tags: html, css, center

I'm making a Christmas calendar for my girlfriend. I have some issues with centering the boxes and header. Header its not centered and the boxes starts more to the left than right. I have set the wrapper to margin auto 0. Didnt solve my problem. Any suggestions?

```css
body {
  background: url("http://hamawandi.com/images/bg4.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  font-size:30;
  margin: 0;
  color: #666;
}

.wrapper {
  width:70%;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  margin-top:50px;
}

.calender-box {
  width:130px;
  height:130px;
  background-image: url('/images/background-xmas3.png');
 float:left;
  border: 5px dotted red;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
   text-align:center;
  font-size:45px;
  color:white;
  line-height:140px;
  text-decoration: none;

}

.header{
  font-size:40px;
  color:white;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top:-10px;

}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header">
❄ Julekalender 2016 ❄
</div>
<a href="/luke1.php" class="calender-box">1</a>
<a href="/luke1.php" class="calender-box">2</a>
<a href="/luke1.php" class="calender-box">3</a>
<a href="/luke1.php" class="calender-box">4</a>
<a href="/luke1.php" class="calender-box">5</a>
<a href="/luke1.php" class="calender-box">6</a>
<a href="/luke1.php" class="calender-box">7</a>
<a href="/luke1.php" class="calender-box">8</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a table? Granted, a calender might not be a table, strictly speaking, but one could argue that days (in a week) are the column names, and you could then make the point that a calendar strictly speaking IS a table.

Comment: Problem is that your wrapper is 70%, and that is more width than x boxes in row (inspect element and you will see difference, empty space at the right hand side)... So, your wrapper should have exact width of desired boxes number in a row.... Also, should calendar be responsive, e.g. 4,3 or 2 boxes per row, relatively to screen width?

Answer (score 2):

My approach would be using [flexbox](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp):

```css
body {
background: url("http://hamawandi.com/images/bg4.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size: cover;
font-size:30;
margin: 0;
color: #666;
}

.wrapper {
width: 70%;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-top: 50px;
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
/* you must add vendor prefixes to flexbox properties for cross-browser compatibility */
}

.header {
font-size: 40px;
color: white;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: -10px;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
}

.calender-box {
width: 130px;
height: 130px;
background-image: url(/images/background-xmas3.png);
float: none;
border: 5px dotted red;
margin-left: 0;
margin-bottom: 10px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 45px;
color: white;
line-height: 140px;
text-decoration: none;
}

a {
width: 130px;
height: auto;
display: inline-block;
border: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header">❄ Julekalender 2016 ❄</div>
<a href="/luke1.php" class="calender-box">1</a>
<a href="/luke1.php" class="calender-box">2</a>
<a href="/luke1.php" class="calender-box">3</a>
<a href="/luke1.php" class="calender-box">4</a>
<a href="/luke1.php" class="calender-box">5</a>
<a href="/luke1.php" class="calender-box">6</a>
<a href="/luke1.php" class="calender-box">7</a>
<a href="/luke1.php" class="calender-box">8</a>
<a></a>
<a></a>
<a></a>
<a></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The wrapper is actually perfectly centered in your example. It's just that the 70% area could only fit so many boxes and those boxes float left.

Any extra room is to the right of the last box which fits.

[image]
*Notice the blue lines on both sides of the boxes which show where your wrapper div starts and ends.*

You could make those boxes centered instead of float left or make the wrapper bigger like I do below.

Comment: Did you see how your code works on different resolutions? On bigger screens wrapper is not centered at all...

Comment: @Nevermind I posted a screen-shot of what I see on bigger resolution with dev-tools, and updated answer.

Comment: Yes, right. However, we will need some explanations about desired behavior from OP. I think that maybe flex could solve problem...